# Automatic Login after Sign up on AAD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I want to login the user automatically to my application after successful registration using the Azure Active Directory. At the moment it redirects the user to the login page.

The code for the register is the following:

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IUser newUser = new User();
            activeDirectoryClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();

            newUser.DisplayName = model.Name + " " + model.Surname;
            newUser.UserPrincipalName = model.UserName;
            newUser.AccountEnabled = true;
            newUser.MailNickname = model.Name;                
            newUser.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile                
            {
                Password = model.Password,
                ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false
            };
            newUser.UsageLocation = "US";

            try
            {
                activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError creating new user {0} {1}", e.Message,
                    e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

The code for the login is:

```
public void Login()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the register and login-in are two different concepts of the web app. It is expected that redirect to the login-in the page after register we shouldn’t mix to use them.

The Azure Active Directory supports to use [OpenId connect](http://openid.net/connect/) to authenticate the relying party however it doesn’t support to authenticate without users sign-in.